# UITableView - We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to use the self-resizing cell in one of my custom cell in UITableview. This is for the varying address field so as the address length increases the table cell should also increase with the UILabel.

I am using the following constraints:

[image: UILabel]

[image: Constraints to the UITableView]

The error in console is:

[image]

Moreover, the table view is not showing this cell because of this. I have given :

1. UITableViewAutomaticDimension

For both estimatedHeightForRow and heightForRow

2. UILabel number of lines as 0

What is the issue and why it is happening?

Comment: Did you forget to add top constraint?

Comment: i haven't added this. You mean i need to add the top constriant to the main office label or to the subview?

Comment: Top constraint of the label is essential for the cell to calculate its height.

Comment: So what are the constraints required for this label . please answer. It will be of great help

Comment: Add the top constraint and check if it is working

Comment: yeah it is working. Thanks man. But please do tell why we need top constraint for calculating height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the height of UITableViewCell, vertical constraints top and bottom of the corresponding subviews which you are considering relevant for height calculation must be connected to the other subviews in such a way that it eventually connects top and bottom constraint to the superview ie UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

Add top and bottom constraints to Main office label and other subviews also.